# Will You Take Coffee or Tea?

Tags: logical-deduction

Claire, Katia and Lila like to have dinner together.

1. Each of them always orders either coffee or tea after dinner.
2. If Claire orders coffee, then Katia orders the drink that Lila orders.
3. If Katia orders coffee, then Claire orders the drink that Lila doesn't order.
4. If Lila orders tea, then Claire orders the drink that Katia orders.

According to these constraints, which of them must always order the same drink?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simpler proof of the solution already given by the other two answers:

> Let's assume Claire orders coffee. By condition 1, Katia and Lila both order the same thing, either coffee or tea.

- > If it's coffee, then they're all drinking the same thing, contradicting condition 2.
- > If it's tea, then Claire is drinking something different from the others, contradicting condition 3.

Either way we have a contradiction, so

> Claire is always ordering tea.

Comment: I don't get it... can't we just as easily say Lila always orders coffee and also satisfy all the conditions?

Comment: @musefan Yes exactly, Lila ordering coffee or Lila ordering tea are both possible. Here I've found a combination which is *not* possible, which answers the question.

Comment: I get what you are saying, and it's clearly what the OP intended. However, I could say `all 3 order the same drink every time: Claire = tea, Katia = tea, Lila = coffee` and there is no information in the question that contradicts that being a correct answer. Surely the question should only have one valid answer?

Comment: @musefan I think you're not getting exactly what the puzzle is. Yes, there is no unique answer to "what are all of these three people drinking" but there is a unique answer to "under the given constraints, which of these three people must always order the same drink", which is the puzzle to be solved here. In fact, the question suggests that they *often* have dinner together, so maybe the exact configuration of drinks varies from time to time, but one person is always ordering the same thing every time - the question asks which one of them that is.

Comment: But I just gave you an answer that fits "under the given constraints...". "Often" doesn't imply that any of them change their drink choice. It also isn't specific that **only one** person orders the same drink. Which I feel is the part that I have a problem with. I don't think a question should require assumptions outside of the information provided. I believe it should have a specific rule that states only one person ever orders the same drink, that way it can only have the one valid answer as you have provided.

Comment: @musefan You just gave me an answer *to what*? You gave a valid answer to "who orders which drink" but that's **not what the question is asking**: in the question above, the puzzle is literally "Who always orders the same drink?"

Comment: Q: Who always orders the same drink? A: All 3 of them do. "Who" isn't limited to just being one person.

Comment: @musefan No, because the question suggests that they *often* have dinner together, so maybe the exact configuration of drinks varies from time to time, but one person is always ordering the same thing every time - the question asks which one of them that is. Three people "like to have dinner together", certain constraints are "always" true (i.e. every time they dine together), so which one of them "always" orders the same drink? I guess that "always" could be changed to "must always, under the above constraints", to be completely rigorous - would that resolve your issue?

Comment: Sure, *maybe* the configuration changes, but equally *maybe* it doesn't change. I get that it is impossible for Claire to order coffee, but that doesn't mean the others don't always order the same thing. If I claim that "Katia always orders tea" there is nothing in the question you can use to prove my answer wrong. Therefore the question has multiple valid answers. The question should say something that ensures only one person ever orders the same drink. e.g. "5. only one person ever orders the same drink". I don't believe a question should have multiple valid answers, that is all I am saying.

Comment: @musefan I've made an edit to the question to clarify this point - does it look better now?

Comment: Yes, not the wording I would have chosen, but I can no longer defend my argument so it does the job.

Answer (score 11):

> Claire does - always tea.

Because:

> The possible orders, and which rule prevents it:
>
> ```
> C | K | L
> ---------
> T | T | T
> T | T | C
> T | C | T (3 & 4)
> T | C | C
> C | T | T (4)
> C | T | C (2)
> C | C | T (2)
> C | C | C (3)
> ```

> Of the remaining options, Claire always has tea.

Comment: You got it ! Good job.

Comment: TCT also violates #3 as well as #4

Comment: Ah yes, I transcribed quickly after just crossing them off on paper without tracking rules - I'll update

Answer (score 5):

Another way of looking at the problem:

Rule 1 means that

> we can suppose Claire, Katia and Lila are Boolean variables! Let coffee be true, and tea be false.

So we can write the other rules as

> (2) If C, then K = L

> (3) If K, then C != L

> (4) If !L, then C = K

> Suppose C. Then K leads to a contradiction by (3), and !K leads to a contradiction by (4). Therefore !C, and Claire always orders tea.

Comment: Nice. I would change tea be true and coffee be false, though =D

Comment: Nice work, sleuth ! You got it.